# Add js lib to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I want to connect it with a lib inside the component.
For example I want to create a map component and  I dpn't want to use any existing wrappers for mapboxGl. I want to use it like this https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'> inside the component. I know that I can connect it in index.html, but is there a way to connect from component. 
Something like

```
import map from 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js';
```

**And what is there is no npm module for this lib?**

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a good way forward: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using npm to gather packages to react.

```
npm install --save mapbox-gl
```

Then you will be able to import this package to your project